# xrandr scaling: blurry fonts when downscaling

Tags: x11, xrandr

Is there any option to downscale the monitor without getting blurry fonts?

I am forced to work on 1366x768 monitor at the moment, which is painful due to low amount of content I can pack on my screen (I'm coding).

I've tried

`> $ xrandr --output LVDS1 --scale 1.2x1.2 --panning <new scaled resolution> [±master ●●]`

which helped a bit, but fonts look just super-bad. Any option for this?

Comment: Scaling using filtering, so everything will be blurry by design. Try changing the resolution instead, and adjust font sizes if necessary.

Comment: well yeah.. problem is that this monitor supports only max of 1366x768. :) I presumed that there should be some clever algorithm for scaling without blurring.. if not, too bad, but nothing can be done :)

Comment: Using 1366x768 with smaller fonts will work a lot better than scaling down with larger fonts. And no, there's no clever algorithm to scale without blurring, leaving aside the problem that the scaling is done in hardware, so you can't change the algorithm. That's why you have fonts of different sizes in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

i did `xrandr --output <output> --scale 0.8x0.8`

and it was blurry, then afterwards

`xrandr --output <output> --scale 1x1`

and it was much better quality and scaled down too. Now I have both lines in my startup script and it works perfectly with a sleep interval of 10 seconds.

Might be specific to my monitor or maybe the OS (elementary), because it seems like a weird trick that shouldn't work quite like it does.

Comment: Well, returning back to 1x1 is returning it to default value. I don't think this is what you wanted